# Nested Blazor components in MVC applications

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, blazor

I have added Blazor components to my existing MVC application following [This Guide.](https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/) This is working as intended and I am able to get Blazor components to render however I am having trouble creating a simple list using Blazor components as I am unable to get components nesting correctly.

I have got the following code working in a Blazor application correctly rendering a simple list;

*SimpleList.blazor*

```
<ol>
    @ChildContent
</ol>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

*SimpleListItem.blazor*

```
<li>
    <span>@Text</span>
</li>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

*Index.razor*

```
<SimpleList>
    <SimpleListItem Text="Item 1"></SimpleListItem>
    <SimpleListItem Text="Item 2"></SimpleListItem>
</SimpleList>
```

When using these components in a blazor application show above, this produces the desired result of an ordered list with two items. However as using the blazor component name directly in MVC applications [is not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6348#issuecomment-704217142) I am instead making use of the  helper tag and am currently doing the following;

*Index.cshtml*

```
<component type="typeof(Components.SimpleList)" render-mode="Server">
    <component type="typeof(Components.SimpleListItem)" render-mode="Server" param-Text="@("Item 1")"/>
    <component type="typeof(Components.SimpleListItem)" render-mode="Server" param-Text="@("Item 2")"/>
</component>
```

This is however does not work, the list items are not being rendered inside the list and the following HTML is being generated

*Generated HTML*

```
<ol><!--!--></ol>
<li><span>Item 1</span></li>
<li><span>Item 2</span></li>
```

Am I doing something incorrectly or are nested components not supported in MVC applications?

Answer (score 1):

The `<component>` tag itself cannot be nested in that way. It can render a **single** component (which itself may then have nested Razor components).

If `Index.razor` is accessible in this context, you might try

```html
<component type="typeof(Components.Index)" render-mode="Server">
</component>
```

The tag helper is rendering the first component `SimpleList` but the child content is empty, hence

```html
<ol><!--!--></ol>
```

Then the tag helper renders the inner items: two `SimpleListItem` references which results in

```html
<li><span>Item 1</span></li>
<li><span>Item 2</span></li>
```

Comment: That's unfortunate, Don't suppose there is a workaround for MVC applications is there?

Comment: No. You’ll have upgrade to full Blazor to get the proper awesomeness. Note you can have a hybrid MVC-Blazor app with both MVC controllers+views _and_ Blazor pages.

Comment: That sounds like it could work, is this something that can be integrated into an existing MVC application or would it require the creation of a new Blazor app?

Comment: Assuming it's ASP.NET Core and running .NET Core 3.1 or NET 5+ it should work. Our main web app was upgraded from ASP.NET (Framework) to .NET Core 3.1 and then we added the Blazor Server-side support. We have existing pages using MVC, some Razor Pages (.cshtml) and new pages are created as Blazor (.razor) files. You should create basic Blazor Server apps and compare your app with that version to see what changes are need. Be assured it does work.